# How in Ubuntu 16.04 can I move .steam out of encrypted home to a linked unencrypted folder?

Tags: 16.04, directory, steam

My ~ folder is encrypted. I would like certain sub folders to be moved to 'not encrypted' folders.
In particular this includes .steam/

Should I consider having .steam/ and other unencrypted folders as symbolic links to a locations outside the ~ structure?

Thank you.